# App crashes when nothing is entered in the TextBoxes I'm trying to parse

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing an app for windows phone in Visual Studio and it's my first time using C# language in general because I'm an Android developer and I can't figure out why my app crashes on button press if nothing is entered.

If someone could help that would be awesome. Thanks alot!!

```
private void sum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    decimal n1 = decimal.Parse(num1.Text);
    decimal n2 = decimal.Parse(num2.Text);
    decimal n3 = decimal.Parse(num3.Text);

    if (n1.Equals(null) || n2.Equals(null) || n3.Equals(null))
    {
        sum1.Text = "Enter something!";
    }
    else
    {
        decimal sum = n1 + n2 + n3;
        String m = Convert.ToString(sum);
        sum1.Text = m;
    }
}
```

Comment: decimal.parse will cause an error if you say entered "a" .. its not a valid number.. so, you need to test for the error, not nulls.

Comment: "c language" != c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attempting to parse empty text fields (or fields with invalid data) is the most likely candidate for throwing an exception and causing a crash. Also, the result of `decimal.Parse` is not going to be `null`, so the `if` portion of your `if/else` block won't execute.

I'd recommend using [`decimal.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which allows you to do something (like display your message) when parsing fails.

```
private void sum_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    decimal n1;
    decimal n2;
    decimal n3;

    if (decimal.TryParse(num1.Text, out n1)
        && decimal.TryParse(num2.Text, out n2)
        && decimal.TryParse(num3.Text, out n3))
    {
        decimal sum = n1 + n2 + n3;
        String m = Convert.ToString(sum);
        sum1.Text = m;
    }
    else
    {
        sum1.Text = "One or more fields has a missing/invalid value.";
    }
}
```